# Using BroadcastReceiver to launch MediaProjection API on Android 10

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-mediaprojection

I have been looking around for approximately 6 hours, I have never needed to ask a thing on StackOverflow because almost everytime I either come up with a solution or someone has already done it before. But this time, it got a little complicated for me and nothing worked, not even thorough searching yielded any results.

**The Goal:** I am building a very small Android App that launches MediaProjection API service (Recording the screen for a second or so) upon receiving a BroadcastReceiver's intent.

**The Issue:** However, in order to launch MediaProjection API service I need the special data that is returned from the permission request from onActivityResult (some IBinder magic token or something) which can only be obtained from an activity.

- The MediaProjection API works extremely fine when I run it from an activity/fragment. Yet it fails hard when I run it from a BroadcastReceiver, for one causal reason I will be mentioning in a minute.

**What I tried:** So in order to pass that "magic token" (which is an Intent object that is returned upon requesting the recording permission, I tried turning it into JSON and saving it in SharedPreferences, only to retrieve it later when the BroadcastReceiver is fired. I retrieve it successfully, and I deserialize it back to an Intent object, all using Gson. (this seems to be the step that ruins everything, the deserialization step).

**What I think is the exact problem**: So I assume Gson just can't deserialize properly the Intent object in order to use it to start recording. The app crashes due to NullPointerException when I instantiate MediaProjectionManager, it just returns null, as if it doesn't exist, as if I never instantiated it in the first place.

**My question**: How can I run MediaProjection API successfully from a BroadcastReceiver without having to pass its Intent data through a json serialization/deserialization process ?

Comment: Hold onto the `Intent` as an object. The `Intent` is only good for your current process. `SharedPreferences` is for things that need to live beyond the lifetime of your process.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Indeed. I have come to the realization that I cannot hold onto an Intent for longer than the app's lifespan. Thanks for your reply. Question can be closed.